# Can I use SRV to receive mail on port 2525 ? How must I configure it in my DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp

Is it possible to use a SRV rule on my DNS to receive mail on port 2525 instead of port 25 ?
If it is possible how can I setup this rule correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a purely theoretical level it would be possible to do so using `SRV` records but what prevents this from being applicable to your problem is that MTAs only make use of `MX` and address records (`A`/`AAAA`). Ie, in practice no one would look up your `SRV` record if you added one.

In effect `SRV` can be seen as a generalised and extended version of the `MX` record type and it would be greatly beneficial if it was used with more protocols. Unfortunately it was introduced too late to be a factor in the specification of many major protocols that have been around for a long time (HTTP is probably the archetypical example of this, SMTP not as much as it at least has its own specialised `MX` record type which solves most of the same problems).

Answer (score 2):

No.

> The MX mechanism does not grant the ability to provide mail service on
>   alternative port numbers @wikipedia

Comment: Ok then i am gonna use a tcp proxy